# How to disable CKeditor removing tags

Tags: html, tags, ckeditor

How do I disable CKeditor removing tags like `<div>` because it deems it not needed but I need it?

Thanks.

Comment: Try to add more information. What does it do and what do you expect it to do nad what have you tried?

Answer (score 6):

Assume that you have defined your editor like this:

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
```

then add this configuration:

```
editor.config.allowedContent = true;
```

**OR**

in `config.js`, just add this

```
config.allowedContent = true;
```